# DNS failover takes time

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, dns

I have a C# web service on IIS acting like a proxy. My problem is that when the IP address of one of the backend servers change, the windows DNS cache is correctly updated (checked with nslookup) but the service continues to do some requests on the old IP for about 40 minutes.

I noticed that the failover works if I stop hitting the proxy for 5 minutes but it is not an acceptable solution, the failover should be automatic.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you looking up the DNS entries in your web service? In general, you don't want to be hitting DNS servers on every request so this may not be the best way of doing failover. What causes the IP address of the back end servers to change?

Comment: I agree with you, using DNS for failover is a bad idea. Unfortunately, it is the way it is done on the backend server and I have no control over it. The IP address changes because the backend server moves from one data center to another.

Comment: Can you post the code that incorrectly resolves the IP?

Comment: Well, what exactly do you *want* to happen and how do you want it to work? You have a few options: wait for the DNS cache to expire (and live with failed requests for a long time), poll DNS on every request (and live with the performance hit), or come up with something else.

Comment: The DNS entry has a TTL of 30 seconds so I expect every web requests to hit the new IP after 30 seconds. My issue is that the code on my web service still sends requests to the old IP even if the entry in the DNS cache is correct.

Code is too long to post it here but basically: I create a HttpWebRequest and use it asynchronously (IASyncResult, AsyncCallback)

Comment: _"any idea"_ - sure, don't rely on Stupid DNS Tricks(TM) to work around your network problems!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting this on your server Web.config:

```
<configuration> 
   <system.webServer> 
      <httpProtocol allowKeepAlive="false" /> 
   </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

This tells the server that [it can't send back the `Connection: Keep-Alive` header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms524563%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). New connections are created for every request and this somehow forces it to update to the new IP. When Keep Alive is left enabled it would keep going on that shared connection to the old IP for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the negative cache timeout to zero?  I know you said the dns cache is correctly updated, but if you hit it even once when it was outdated, you may be stuck using the old IP until it expires.

On Windows XP, you set it in the registry as:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Dnscache\Parameters
DWORD: MaxNegativeCacheTtl
Value:  0

Haven't played with this in Vista or Windows 7.

I'm curious to see the code that's failing to resolve the backend server address... wondering if something in the code itself is holding on to the old IP.

Comment: the negative cache is how to long to store _negative_ (i.e. missing) answers.  it has no effect on _changed_ answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something built on the windows http components, you will find that the component hangs on to the resolved ip as a performance "optimization". Once it has a name/ip match, it will hang onto it for literally DAYS. It completely ignores TTL's.

The only reason why you are overcoming this with an idle delay is because the component is recycling in your particular usage.

It's a known problem. The MS program manager "sort of" admits to it. But, it has never been fixed.

We wrote our own replacement.

Comment: I'm suspecting something like this and was wishing someone could help me pointing it out. So I can't avoid the "dirty" patch...?